# Hacer filtro de mes de campo fecha("Y-m-d")

Tags: php

hola tengo este formulario quiero hacer el filtro con solo el mes que al seleccionar un me
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
   
      
       <?php
          
           if(isset($_POST["mes"])&& $_POST["mes"]>0)
            $consulta.=" AND s.fecha=".$_POST['mes'];
           
           
           
     
$so ="SELECT s.Id_folio, s.fecha, d.id_departamento, d.nombre,s.descripcion_trabajo, s.observaciones, s.Id_servicio,s.tipo_solicitud, s.costo,  s.id_vehiculo, u.Empleado_Nombre, u.Empleado_id, t.Id_servicio, t.Nombre_servicio,s.Autoriza_Soli,s.Autoriza_Ger,s.Autoriza_GerIs,s.Autoriza_trab,s.Autoriza_termi FROM solicitud as s, departamento as d ,usuarios as u, tipo_servicio as t  WHERE s.id_departamento=d.id_departamento and s.Empleado_id =u.Empleado_id and s.Id_servicio =t.Id_servicio and  Autoriza_Soli=1 and Autoriza_Ger =2 and Autoriza_GerIs=3 and Autoriza_trab=4 and Autoriza_termi=5 ".$consulta."";
           
     
                   $mostrarso=mysql_query($so);
      while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');//en esta parte divido mi campo fecha para que me muestre solo el mes con nombre
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
$nombremes=strftime("%B", strtotime($fecha_mes=$i[1]));
$fecha_mes=$i[1];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]} "

                ?>
```

¿pero como puedo hacer la consulta de mes ?

Comment: que te devuelve mes? , como es el formato

Comment: mes es mi input que me devuelve mis meses<td>Mes:<input value="Mes"type="month" name="mes" id="mes"></td>

Answer (score 1):

primero obtén el mes de la s.fecha con la función MONTH de mysql y comparalo con el mes que te llega por $_POST['mes'] este debe ser numerico

ejemplo:

```
$consulta.=" AND MONTH(s.fecha)=".$_POST['mes'];
```

s.fecha debe estar definida como fecha en tu tabla

Comment: if(isset($_POST["mes"])&& $_POST["mes"]>0)
 $consulta.="AND MONTH(s.fecha)=MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(".$_POST['mes'].", '%d-%m-%Y'))";
           
           quedaria asi?

Comment: perdón el mes no hay que convertirlo ya quedaría de la siguiente manera $consulta.=" AND MONTH(s.fecha)=".$_POST['mes'];

Comment: el mes es mi input donde selecciono los meses ,lo puse de esta manera          if(isset($_POST["mes"])&& $_POST["mes"]>0)
           $consulta.=" AND MONTH(s.fecha)=".$_POST['mes'];   pero no me funciono

Comment: revisa  si $_POST['mes']  te llega con valor numérico